# Python/Django Model with 2 or more foreign keys of the same name

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm getting an error which states that my group model has more than one Foreign key to Person

```
personid = models.ForeignKey(Person, db_column='PersonId', related_name='Persons',
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True )
createdby = models.ForeignKey(Person, db_column='createdBy', related_name='createdPerson',
                                  on_delete=models.SET_NULL, max_length=36, blank=True, null=True,)
archivedby = models.ForeignKey(Person, db_column='archivedBy', related_name='archivedPerson',
                                   on_delete=models.SET_NULL, max_length=36, blank=True, null=True,)
```

I have done some research to resolve this issue and all of the solutions lead me to using the related_name attribute for each model item, which I did. I'm still getting this error. What am I missing? Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to post your exception trace log here. In meanwhile lets try most simple guess - did you apply the migrations after setting related name on FK's?

Comment: Yes I applied my migrations.

Comment: Then next step is to show exception trace.

Comment: It's too long for me to fit in this comment area.

Comment: I'd bet, so just edit the question instead.